# My bootstrap code works in codeply the online compiler but does not work in VS code

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Tindog</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: maybe you didn’t enable bootstrap or did it wrong, because in online compilers it is enabled automatically

Answer (score 0):

Be certain that you include bootstrap either as CDN (like I did in the example below) or locally by linking to the bootstrap.css file which you would do in the header.

For certain elements in the navbar, you will need to also include the bootstrap js on the bottom of your page. Again either as CDN (I also put it in) or again localy linking the bootstrap.js file

I hope the snippet helps

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Tindog</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to link bootsrap or any other cdns you use in local machine..

try this..

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Tindog</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```